# Access on-premises file share from Azure App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App Service which already connects to a on-premises SQL Server database (VNet Integration is configured). I also need to access an on-premises fileshare, which is currently not working (access denied). How can this be achieved? 
I already tried to use the SimpleImpersonation package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleImpersonation/), but this was not working. I'm not sure if this was package to work from an Azure App Service.

Thanks in advance.